# Duda en Python-Tkinter Cuadro que muestre consultas SQL

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica, textbox

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación y he empezado en Python. Por ahora estoy haciendo una aplicación que, al presionar los botones, hace consultas SQL a una base de datos MYSQL. No obstante, tengo la duda de como crear un cuadro que muestre esos resultados MYSQL y he creado un textbox para que lo muestre, pero no sé si es lo más idoneo ni tampoco como hacer la forma para que muestre las consultas.

**Adjunto codigo**

```
**import tkinter
from tkinter import *

#Creación de ventana
window=Tk()
#Tamaño y titulo de la ventana
window.title('SQL Dura Search')
window.geometry("1400x600+10+20")
#Color de la ventana
canvas = Canvas(width=1400, height=600, bg='chartreuse4')
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
canvas.create_line(10, 10, 80, 80)
canvas.create_line(10, 80, 80, 10)
#Ventana que muestra resultados
entry = tkinter.Entry()
entry.place(x=900, y=50, width=400,height=500)
#Botones
btn1=Button(window, text="Pedidos recibidos", fg='blue')
btn1.place(x=10, y=10)
btn2=Button(window, text="Envios realizados", fg='blue')
btn2.place(x=10, y=40)
btn3=Button(window, text="Facturación hasta hoy", fg='blue')
btn3.place(x=10, y=70)
btn4=Button(window, text="Facturación posible", fg='blue')
btn4.place(x=10, y=100)
btn5=Button(window, text="Clientes nuevos", fg='blue')
btn5.place(x=10, y=130)
btn6=Button(window, text="Pedidos de compra", fg='blue')
btn6.place(x=10, y=160)
btn7=Button(window, text="Pedidos de compra facturación", fg='blue')
btn7.place(x=10, y=190)
btn8=Button(window, text="Productos planificados a fabricar", fg='blue')
btn8.place(x=10, y=220)
btn9=Button(window, text="Planificación de los reactores", fg='blue')
btn9.place(x=10, y=250)
btn10=Button(window, text="Ordenes de producción", fg='blue')
btn10.place(x=10, y=280)
btn11=Button(window, text="Coste ordenes de producción", fg='blue')
btn11.place(x=10, y=280)
btn12=Button(window, text="Productos planificados a fabricar", fg='blue')
btn12.place(x=10, y=310)
btn13=Button(window, text="Cobros que vendran este mes", fg='blue')
btn13.place(x=10, y=340)
btn14=Button(window, text="Pagos que vendran este mes", fg='blue')
btn14.place(x=10, y=370)
window.mainloop()**
```

Gracias de antemano.

---

Perdonad, pensaba que incluia el codigo al verlo pero no aparecia. Lo copio aqui nose si se vera bien. Muchas gracias por vuestros consejos y ayuda, lo incluyo aqui a ver si se ve ahora.

Adjunto codigo

```
**import tkinter
from tkinter import *

#Creación de ventana
window=Tk()
#Tamaño y titulo de la ventana
window.title('SQL Dura Search')
window.geometry("1400x600+10+20")
#Color de la ventana
canvas = Canvas(width=1400, height=600, bg='chartreuse4')
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
canvas.create_line(10, 10, 80, 80)
canvas.create_line(10, 80, 80, 10)
#Ventana que muestra resultados
entry = tkinter.Entry()
entry.place(x=900, y=50, width=400,height=500)
#Botones
btn1=Button(window, text="Pedidos recibidos", fg='blue')
btn1.place(x=10, y=10)
btn2=Button(window, text="Envios realizados", fg='blue')
btn2.place(x=10, y=40)
btn3=Button(window, text="Facturación hasta hoy", fg='blue')
btn3.place(x=10, y=70)
btn4=Button(window, text="Facturación posible", fg='blue')
btn4.place(x=10, y=100)
btn5=Button(window, text="Clientes nuevos", fg='blue')
btn5.place(x=10, y=130)
btn6=Button(window, text="Pedidos de compra", fg='blue')
btn6.place(x=10, y=160)
btn7=Button(window, text="Pedidos de compra facturación", fg='blue')
btn7.place(x=10, y=190)
btn8=Button(window, text="Productos planificados a fabricar", fg='blue')
btn8.place(x=10, y=220)
btn9=Button(window, text="Planificación de los reactores", fg='blue')
btn9.place(x=10, y=250)
btn10=Button(window, text="Ordenes de producción", fg='blue')
btn10.place(x=10, y=280)
btn11=Button(window, text="Coste ordenes de producción", fg='blue')
btn11.place(x=10, y=280)
btn12=Button(window, text="Productos planificados a fabricar", fg='blue')
btn12.place(x=10, y=310)
btn13=Button(window, text="Cobros que vendran este mes", fg='blue')
btn13.place(x=10, y=340)
btn14=Button(window, text="Pagos que vendran este mes", fg='blue')
btn14.place(x=10, y=370)
window.mainloop()**
```

Comment: La mejor forma para mostrar cualquier tabla usando tkinter, es usar Treeview del modulo tkinter.ttk, que ofrece widgets adicionales

Comment: Creo que podrías incluir el código con el que ejecutas una consulta, para que quien quiera responderte pueda partir de allí.

Comment: Hola a todos, inclui el codigo en abajo pero no sé si se puede ver aquí, perdon. Gracias por los consejos porque puedo ver otra forma de desarrollar esta aplicacion de escritorio :). Soy nuevo en esto de stackoverflow y no sé si postee bien el codigo o no :(.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que podrías hacer es una consulta de búsqueda general de los datos que quieres traerte, por ejemplo:

> "cobros de este mes"

```
def buscar_datos(dato):

    # SELECT * FROM MIDATABASE
    # donde miconexion es mi objeto de la clase Conexion
    buscar = miconexion.buscar(dato)
    for _ in buscar:
        self.titulo_var.set(_[0])
        self.fecha_var.set(_[1])
        self.hora_var.set(_[2])
        self.descripcion_var.set(_[3])
        self.duracion.set(_[4])
```

luego del for puedes implementar bien colocarlo dentro de tu Text que contiene tu código, o bien de una forma mejor y más ordenada en un treeview para que coloques el nombre de cada item de la lisa que traigas. Otra es que la traigas a unos entry con los label respectivos para cargar los datos y te quede mejor formato, Igual eso depende tu parecer y perspectiva

Answer (score 0):

Si estás buscando mostrar los resultados de tus consultas SQL en una interfaz gráfica, existen varias opciones más adecuadas que un cuadro de texto simple. Una opción común es utilizar un elemento de tabla, como un GridView o un DataGrid.

Comment: Esto parece más un comentario que una respuesta. Aún no tienes privilegios para comentar, así que podrías convertirla en una respuesta completa y comenzar a ganar algo de reputación. En mi opinión, lo que le falta es un pequeño ejemplo. Lamentablemente el AP no muestra código, así que quedas en el aire con qué base de datos usa, pero puedes asumir. Encontrarás más información en [answer].

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, soy nuevo en esto de stackoverflow y no pude ni poner el código bien, cuando pongo el control+k y el codigo me hace la sangria pero no se si se muestra bien, lo he vuelto a postear en un comentario aparte.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, ya he colgado el comentario y el codigo, espero que se vea bien. Tomo nota tambien del GridView y DataGrid, puede ser una alternativa mejor, lo investigaré :).

Comment: Si tenes alguna duda mas de como seguir o que agregar en mi repositorio de github tengo un CRUD de Python por si te puede servir de ayuda. https://github.com/nachodev-git/CRUD-en-Python